# Windows Authentication for IdentityServer doesn't take login without error message

Tags: identityserver4, windows-authentication

I have configured my identityServer to use Windows authentication. My problem is that the Windows Security login box in my browser keeps coming back after submit my Windows login. It looks like that the userid or password are incorrect but there is no error messages:

[image]

I have tried different formats of credential, such as with the "\MyDomain" in user name and without, but it made no difference. And I know my Windows credential is correct because that what I use everyday to log into the network. I also tried different browsers - Edge and Chrome, no difference either. Does anyone know what might be going on? How do I debug an issue like this?

**Update**

Just noticed that my problem might be caused by the fact that my Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl) function in ExternalController gets invoked repeatedly. Here is the function:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

    // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
    {
        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
    }
    
    // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)), 
        Items =
        {
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl }, 
            { "scheme", scheme },
        }
    };
    return Challenge(props, scheme);
}
```

When I run it in debugging, this function gets called twice after the Windows authentication option is selected and before the Windows Security login box displays on browser, and again, after the login submission. But the Callback() functions which calls HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync never gets invoked. There are no source code for the caller that I can track down. Who is invoking this function? Why is it invoked again after login is submitted? What am I doing wrong here?

**Update-1**

Besides the Challenge function I posted above, here is my Login function I modified (by adding the invocation of at the ChallengeWindowsAsync top), and the ChallengeWindowsAsync(returnUrl) function I added to AccountController.cs. I commented out the invocation of ChallengeWindowsAsync later as I thought it was not needed because the Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl) function in ExternalController.cs took care of the Windows authentication.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    //// trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync
    //await ChallengeWindowsAsync(returnUrl);

    // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
    {
        // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
        return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { scheme = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
    }

    return View(vm);
}

private async Task<IActionResult> ChallengeWindowsAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    // see if windows auth has already been requested and succeeded
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows");
    if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
    {
        // we will issue the external cookie and then redirect the
        // user back to the external callback, in essence, treating windows
        // auth the same as any other external authentication mechanism
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", "Windows" },
            }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Windows");

        // the sid is a good sub value
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));

        // the account name is the closest we have to a display name
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

        // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
        var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

        // translate group SIDs to display names
        var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
        id.AddClaims(roles);


        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
            props);
        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }
    else
    {
        // trigger windows auth
        // since windows auth don't support the redirect uri,
        // this URL is re-triggered when we call challenge
        return Challenge("Windows");
    }
}
```

**Update-2**

Modified my Login() and Challenge() as below but still have the same issue - the Windows Security login box keeps coming back. I also noticed that the Login() function only gets invoked once - before the IdentitySever page with authentication options being displayed. After that, only Challenge() gets called, repeatedly. What am I doing wrong?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    if (vm.ExternalLoginScheme == "Windows")
    {
        var authenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows").ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (authenticationResult.Succeeded && authenticationResult?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal windowsPrinciple)
        {
            // Add your custom code here
            var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
                Items =
                {
                    { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                    { "scheme", "Windows"},
                }
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(authenticationResult.Principal);
            return Redirect(authProps.RedirectUri);
        }
        else
        {
            return Challenge("Windows");
        }
    }
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

    // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
    {
        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
    }
    
    // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)), 
        Items =
        {
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl }, 
            { "scheme", scheme },
        }
    };

    return Challenge(props, scheme);
    
}
```

**Update-3**
Here is my Login.cshtml file

```
@model LoginViewModel

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="lead">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>Choose how to login</p>
    </div>

    <partial name="_ValidationSummary" />

    <div class="row">

        @if (Model.EnableLocalLogin)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>Local Account</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form asp-route="Login">
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Username"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" asp-for="Username" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            @if (Model.AllowRememberLogin)
                            {
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="RememberLogin">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="RememberLogin">
                                            Remember My Login
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }

                            <div>
                                <p>The default users are alice/bob, password: Pass123$</p>
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" value="login">Login</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.VisibleExternalProviders.Any())
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>External Account</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            @foreach (var provider in Model.VisibleExternalProviders)
                            {
                                <li class="list-inline-item">
                                    <a class="btn btn-secondary"
                                       asp-controller="External"
                                       asp-action="Challenge"
                                       asp-route-scheme="@provider.AuthenticationScheme"
                                       asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
                                        @provider.DisplayName
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @if (!Model.EnableLocalLogin && !Model.VisibleExternalProviders.Any())
        {
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <strong>Invalid login request</strong>
                There are no login schemes configured for this request.
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update-4**

Here is the ConfigureServices and Configure functions of my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

    var connstr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IDSConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connstr));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
    })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

    // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

    // configures IIS in-proc settings
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // for Windows authentication.
    services.AddAuthentication() // for "Google" login.
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

            options.ClientId = "....apps.googleusercontent.com";
            options.ClientSecret = "....";
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }

    // uncomment if use MVC
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    // Add IdentityServer to the pipeline
    // UseIdentityServer includes a call to UseAuthentication, so it’s not necessary to have both
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    // uncomment if use MVC
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems like your app is in an infinite loop, you can attach a breakpoint in `AccountController` where you have implemented windows authentication code. Usually in `AccountController -> Login()`.

Comment: @Mahesh Just updated my original post above. After removing some of my old code now I can see, yes, I think you are right, the code appears to be running in a loop. But why? How do I break the loop? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out this issue. I am aware that there are many things can cause the same or similar symptom but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666498/windows-authentication-fail-with-401-unauthorized/67109283#67109283) fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

Before invoking the `Challenge()` method make sure that whether the user is already logged-in or not. Please see below sample code.

```
[HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
 if(loginViewModel.ExternalLoginScheme == "Windows")
 {
   var authenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows").ConfigureAwait(false);
   if (authenticationResult.Succeeded && authenticationResult?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal windowsPrinciple)
   {
     // Add your custom code here
     var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
                    Items =
                    {
                        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                        { "scheme", "Windows"},
                    }
                };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync();

    return Redirect(RedirectUri);
   }
   else
   {
     return Challenge("Windows");
   }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I got your problem and found the solution as well, have a look at the below code and update your `startup.cs` file for the same.

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });
```

**Reference**: Read ID4 docs [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html).

Comment: Thank you so much @Mahesh! Please excuse my ignorance on this as I am still new to this stuff. I guess I am still not quite clear about the flow between the Login() and the Challenge(). Please see my new "Update-1" above in which I added my current Login function.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion (see Update-2 above) but still have the same issue. For some reason, the condition loginViewModel.ExternalLoginScheme == "Windows" never evaluated true - the Login() only gets called once when it was early and the oginViewModel.ExternalLoginScheme was still null. After that only the Challenge() gets called. I think that's why I am in a loop. But why Login() is not invoked when it should be?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly you are requesting windows authentication from the client-side, if you have injected windows auth as an external login provider then ID4's sample code creates a button on the login screen, and when the user clicks on that button it would pass `windows` scheme along with a login request.

Comment: I would suggest verifying the code of `Login.cshtml` file.

Comment: I am just using the IdentityServer4's quickstart sample code, the MVC client, almost without modification. And yes, you are right, I am testing using the "Windows" button on the login screen. But in my case, as I described above, the Login() was called BEFORE the login screen displayed, when the oginViewModel.ExternalLoginScheme was still null. When the login screen displays after that, and I click on the button, the Login() function never invoked again, only the Challenge() functions gets called a couple of times.

Comment: I will examine the Login.cshtml file as you suggested Mahesh. I also posted the Login.cshtml file above as Update-3. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look at it!

Comment: Thanks again @Mahesh. I apologize that I didn't include the Startup.cs functions in my original post. I just added them with my Update-4. As you can see, I do have the code you mentioned in my ConfigureServices function, and so it must not be the cause of my issue.

Comment: Strange, it should have worked. At least `LoginScheme` should not be `NULL`. I will try something from my end and will update you.

Comment: Thank you so much Mahesh! I really appreciate your help! Not sure if it is right or wrong, but I keep having this feeling that my control flow is somehow incorrect - as I mentioned before, the only time Loin() gets called was before the identityserver's login page (on which the Windows button presents) even displays. I would expect that the ExternalLoginScheme is null at that time, as I haven't had a chance to click on the Windows button yet. The Login() never gets called again. Only the Challenge() gets called multiple times. So who is supposed to call Login() and when? How do I debug this?