# Windows authentication fail with "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I have a MVC client accessing a Web API protected by IDS4. They all run on my local machine and hosted by IIS. The app works fine when using local identity for authentication. But when I try to use Windows authentication, I keep getting "401 Unauthorized" error from the dev tool and the login box keeps coming back to the browser.

[image]

[image]

Here is the Windows Authentication IIS setting

[image]

and enabled providers

[image]

It's almost like that the user ID or password was wrong, but that's nearly impossible because that's the domain user ID and password I use for logging into the system all the time. Besides, according to my reading, Windows Authentication is supposed to be "automatic", which means I will be authenticated silently without a login box in the first place.

**Update**

I enabled the IIS request tracing and here is the result from the log:

[image]

As you can see from the trace log item #29, the authentication (with the user ID I typed in, "DOM\Jack.Backer") was successful. However, some authorization item (#48) failed after that. And here is the detail of the failed item:

[image]

What's interesting is that the ErrorCode says that the operation (whatever it is) completed successfully, but still I received a warning with a HttpStatus=401 and a HttpReason=Unauthorized. Apparently, this is what failed my Windows Authentication. But what is this authorization about and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone interested - I finally figured this one out. It is because the code that I downloaded from IndentityServer4's quickstart site in late 2020 doesn't have some of the important pieces needed for Windows authentication. Here is what I had to add to the Challenge function of the ExternalController class

[image]

and here is the ProcessWindowsLoginAsync function

```
private async Task<IActionResult> ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
    if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName },
            }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.Identity.Name));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

        if (AccountOptions.IncludeWindowsGroups)
        {
            var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
            var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
            var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
            id.AddClaims(roles);
        }

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id), props);

        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }
    else
    {
        return Challenge(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
    }
}
```

Now my windows authentication works with no issues.